# How do I install this mysql workbench package?

Tags: installation, debian, deb

I want to install

mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-1ubu1010-amd64.deb

on Ubuntu, what is the command line to do that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.33b-1ubu1010-amd64.deb
```

It won't cause a problem because I install workbench every 2 months or so but a small warning: it is recommended that you read the dpkg manual page before using dpkg, as improper use may break the package management database. To view the manual page for dpkg type `man dpkg` on the command line.